# Cloning an AWS apigateway API from existing apigateway from CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have to create many AWS apigateway apis. All apis will use a Lambda function for invocation. These new apis will also include below common steps.

- API type as Regional and a REST API
- Add a POST Method
- Method Execution Settings
- Invocation Type=Lambda Function and also choose respective Lambda
  Function.
- CORS Settings
- Lambda Permissions
- Integration Response Settings
- Deploy API
- Include stage in API Usageplan
- Redeploy API

Here is apigateway clone API SYNOPSIS.

```
SYNOPSIS
            create-rest-api
          --name <value>
          [--description <value>]
          [--clone-from <value>]
          [--binary-media-types <value>]
          [--minimum-compression-size <value>]
          [--api-key-source <value>]
          [--endpoint-configuration <value>]
          [--policy <value>]
          [--api-version <value>]
          [--cli-input-json <value>]
          [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

How to clone an apigateway API from existing apigateway API from CLI and avoid doing all the repeated steps mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below commands as a shell script and execute the script with the mentioned parameters. Parameters names are self explanatory.

Here is the full script and every part is explained.

```
#!/bin/bash
APINAME=${1}
STAGENAME=${2}
LAMBDANAME=${3}
CLONEAPIID=${4}
USAGEPLANID=${5}
AWS_PROFILE=[PROFILENAME]
AWS_REGION=[AWSREGION]
AWS_ACCOUNT=[AWSACCOUNT]
METHOD=POST
```

Clone API from existing API

```
echo "Closing API ${APINAME} from API ${CLONEAPIID}"
RESTAPIID=`aws apigateway create-rest-api --name "${APINAME}" --description "${APINAME}" --clone-from ${CLONEAPIID} --endpoint-configuration '{"types":["REGIONAL"]}' --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} | grep '"id"' | sed 's/,//g;s/ //g;s/"//g;' | awk -F: '{ print $2 }'`
```

Display New Rest API ID

```
echo RESTAPIID: ${RESTAPIID}
```

Getting Resource

```
echo "Getting Resource"
RESOURCEID=`aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id ${RESTAPIID} --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} | grep '"id"' | sed 's/,//g;s/ //g;s/"//g;' | awk -F: '{ print $2 }'`

echo RESOURCEID: ${RESOURCEID}
```

Setting URI and Lambda as Invocation

```
echo "Setting Lambda ${LAMBDANAME}"
LAMBDA_URL="arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS_REGION}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS_REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT}:function:${LAMBDANAME}/invocations"
aws apigateway put-integration --rest-api-id ${RESTAPIID} --resource-id ${RESOURCEID} --http-method ${METHOD} --type AWS --integration-http-method ${METHOD} --uri "${LAMBDA_URL}" --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} | grep uri
```

Generating UUID as statement-id

```
SID=`uuidgen`
```

Adding permissions for API gateway to execute Lambda Function

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name arn:aws:lambda:${AWS_REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT}:function:findPostcode --source-arn arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS_REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT}:${RESTAPIID}/*/*/* --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com --action lambda:InvokeFunction --statement-id ${SID} --profile ${AWS_PROFILE}
```

Setting Integration Response

```
aws apigateway put-integration-response --rest-api-id ${RESTAPIID} --resource-id ${RESOURCEID} --http-method ${METHOD} --status-code 200 --selection-pattern 200 --response-parameters '{"method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'"'"'*'"'"'"}' --selection-pattern "" --response-templates '{"application/json": ""}' --profile ${AWS_PROFILE}
```

Creating Initial Deployment

```
echo "Creating Initial Deployment for ${APINAME} API and Stage ${STAGENAME}"
DEPLOYMENTID=`aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id ${RESTAPIID} --stage-name '' --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} | grep '"id"' | sed 's/,//g;s/ //g;s/"//g;' | awk -F: '{ print $2 }'`
```

Creating Stage

```
aws apigateway create-stage --rest-api-id ${RESTAPIID} --stage-name ${STAGENAME} --description ${STAGENAME} --deployment-id ${DEPLOYMENTID} --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} | grep stageName
sleep 10
```

Adding API stage in Usageplan

```
echo "Adding Stage in Usageplan"
aws apigateway update-usage-plan --usage-plan-id ${USAGEPLANID} --patch-operations op="add",path="/apiStages",value="${RESTAPIID}:${STAGENAME}" --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} | grep name
sleep 10
```

Redeploying Stage

```
echo "Redeploying Stage"
aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id ${RESTAPIID} --stage-name ${STAGENAME} --description ${STAGENAME} --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} | grep description
sleep 5
echo "REST API Endpoints configured and deployed successfully.."
```

Note: Proper time delay (wait) is needed in different steps ( as mentioned in seconds by sleep commands).

Here is an example of executing above shell script.(Assuming script name  cloneapi.sh)

```
./cloneapi.sh MyAPI MyAPIStage MyLambdaFunction apxxxxx upxxxx
```

Where

```
MyAPI is New API Name
MyAPIStage is new API Stage Name
MyLambdaFunction  is Lambda Function Name for New API
apxxxxx is the API ID (Cloning from)
upxxxx is Usage Plan ID
```

The above commands can be used with any AWS CLI version and on any Linux OS, but below is the CLI and OS version used.

aws --version

```
aws-cli/1.15.80 Python/2.7.14 Linux/4.14.94-89.73.amzn2.x86_64 botocore/1.10.79
```

cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

Answer (score 13):

You could clone from existing API when creating new API by the console as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From horse's mouth A.K.A [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-migrate-accounts-regions/)

- Export:

Go to API Gateway and click away as shown in the picture.
[image]

- Creative Step:

  Rename the API title: "title" and all the URI fields to something new "uri" in the exported JSON or YAML (depending which you selected)
- Import

Just create new API and import what you had exported in the previous step.

[image]
[image]