# Lambda triggers not copied when cloning AWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am attempting to clone an AWS API generated from a SAM.

The routes seem to be copied over correctly and link to the same Lambda functions as the original API, but testing shows the API does not have permission to invoke the Lambda functions:

`Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function`

Checking the list of triggers in one of the Lambda functions shows only a trigger for the original API (see below), when I would expect there to now be a second trigger for the cloned API.

If I manually add a trigger for the new API to the Lambda function, this adds a new endpoint to the API with the required permissions, but this defeats the purpose of cloning the original API.

So, is there any way of cloning an AWS REST API in API Gateway, so that new triggers for the new API are automatically added to the relevant Lambda functions?

Or, is there a way of quickly adding the necessary Lambda function triggers from API gateway? Or IAM?

[image: Lambda Triggers]

Comment: How are you trying to clone ?

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary - just in API Gateway in AWS - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56927485/2627160